combine rows based on a common attribute. Merge adjacent cells and list data into that cell
I have a problem similar to this one with some additional features needed.
Excel VBA - Combine rows with duplicate values in one cell and merge values in other cells

| attribute | description  |
|-----------|--------------|
| type 1    | type 1 arms  |
| type 1    | type 1 legs  |
| type 1    | type 1 body  |
| type 2    | type 2 head  |
| type 2    | type 2 wings |
| type 2    | type 2 tail  |

I can use method linked below but i do not know how to do the merging of the adjacent cells and then the operations to put data into the newly merged cells.
Excel VBA - Combine rows with duplicate values in one cell and merge values in other cells

Does it need to be VBA, or would a formula do?

As a formula something like  =BYROW(UNIQUE($A$2:$A$7),LAMBDA(Attribute,TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,FILTER(B2:B7,A2:A7=Attribute)))) would return your merge column.

If you make a start using one of your linked examples, then post your code here, you're more likely to get help with the "problem" part than if you don't post any code at all.

Use Dict object to get the merged Range and values.
Note: The script skips types with only one description because they weren't mentioned in the original post.
Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, objDicVal As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey, arrData
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set objDicVal = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set rngData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    rngData.Sort key1:=rngData.Cells(1), Header:=xlYes
    arrData = rngData.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, 1)
        If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
            Set objDic(sKey) = Union(objDic(sKey), Cells(i, 3))
            objDicVal(sKey) = objDicVal(sKey) & Chr(10) & Cells(i, 2)
        Else
            Set objDic(sKey) = Cells(i, 3)
            objDicVal(sKey) = Cells(i, 2)
        End If
    Next i
    For Each sKey In objDic
        If objDic(sKey).Cells.Count > 1 Then
            objDic(sKey).Merge
            objDic(sKey).Cells(1).Value = objDicVal(sKey)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Microsoft documentation:

Range.Merge method (Excel)


Range.CurrentRegion property (Excel)


Dictionary object

